# Deployment of asp.net application on plesk only particular page

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment, plesk

Actually i deploy my asp project using Plesk. My project in testing phase so the client ask for some changes  in  project. The changes are related to a particular page but after changes i deploy all publish files of my project, which is so time consuming task. Is there is any way to deploy only the particular page from my project.
Thanks....

Comment: You using web-forms ?

Comment: Yes, i am using web-form

Comment: If any changes done in aspx then only copy aspx page in plex, if code changes then you have to copy dll file from bin folder to plex, also you can create ftp for the same so that you can deploy easily.

Comment: what's mean "also you can create ftp for the same"

Answer (score 3):

@Shahid bro, a possible solution can be to use FTP client to upload individual files.